# Aligning side by side in a modal

Tags: html, css

Here is my     [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rnu721kw/),

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="notes">One</div>
    <div class="notes">two</div>
    <div class="notes">three</div>
    <div class="notes">four</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.notes {
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I have a wrapper div which has 300px width.

The inner divs are generated dynamically based on the server request and has the width of 200px each.

Now i need to set side by side in the wrapper and when it reach 300px it needs to be displayed in a scrolled mode..

Seems i have some issues in my code. Pls help...

Comment: This is a popup. Sorry for an extra line :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rnu721kw/2/ Hey, maybe height will help?

Comment: @Nerfair: I need a active scroll bar to view all the child divs

Answer (score 2):

You could give `white-space: nowrap;` to the wrapper, then reset it to `white-space: normal;` for each item.

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rnu721kw/1/)**

```css
#wrapper { white-space: nowrap; }
.notes { white-space: normal; }
```

You might also want to [remove the white-space between inline block elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements). There are several approaches to achieve that, one of them could be setting `font-size: 0` to the parent, then resetting it to `font-size: 16px` on the children.

**[Updated Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rnu721kw/5/)**

Comment: @steeve Please update the fiddle, including the popup.